# PhpStorm @throws tag in method calling other anonymous method

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have a problem with PhpStorm `@throws` tag.

If created an static method for DB transaction:

```
/**
 * Performs a function in a transaction.
 *
 * @param callable $function Function to call.
 *
 * @throws \Throwable
 */
public static function transaction(callable $function) {...}
```

which is simply try which catches any on `\Throwable` and then rollback transactions on DB and rethrows `\Throwable` again.

The problem is that PhpStorm says the method `transaction()` throws `\Throwable` which is correct, so I put that tag in doc block, but in fact that `\Throwable` depends on parameter `$function` passed to method.

So when `$function` throws in fact for example `ModelNotFoundException` then `transaction()` also could only throws that `ModelNotFoundException`.

So when I create code like this:

```
function doSomething(SomeModelClass $model)
{
    Helper::transaction(function () use ($model) {
        $model->otherMethod();
        $model->methodThatCouldThrownAnModelNotFoundException();
        $model->otherMethod2();
        $model->otherMethodEtc();
    });
}
```

PhpStorm says that I need to add try and catch or throw tag.
But it says that transaction throws `\Throwable` but in that case I could be more specific, because I know that it could be only `ModelNotFoundException`. But I cannot put it as `@throws` tag, because then PhpStorm will say, that `trasaction` could only throw `\Throwable`, so I need to remove that tag or add `@throws ModelNotFoundException` to `transaction` doc block.

In that when it will raise 2 warnings:

1. PHPDoc comment doesn't contain all the necessary `@throws` tags
2. Unhandled `\Throwable`.

For now I always add two simple lines with `@noinspection` tag:

```
/**
 * @throws ModelNotFoundException
 * @noinspection PhpDocMissingThrowsInspection
 */
function doSomething(SomeModelClass $model)
{
    /** @noinspection PhpUnhandledExceptionInspection */
    Helper::transaction(function () use ($model) {
        $model->otherMethod();
        $model->methodThatCouldThrownAnModelNotFoundException();
        $model->otherMethod2();
        $model->otherMethodEtc();
    });
}
```

I wonder if there is any way to associate the @throws tag in the `transaction` method with the @throws tag of the method sent as a parameter - `$function`, because it is tiresome to add these comments from `noinspection` every time this method is called.

Comment: For reference purposes: PhpStorm ticket https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-67002

Answer (score 3):

> I wonder if there is any way to associate the @throws tag in the transaction method with the @throws tag of the method sent as a parameter - $function, because it is tiresome to add these comments from noinspection every time this method is called

There isn't or more correctly: none that I know about.

Here is what I know about:

1. Unchecked Exceptions: Name those (generic) exceptions you don't need to check (configure to your benefit, unchecked exceptions are a common Phpstorm feature).
2. Wrap and Bubble: As you turn any exception that happens when calling a function within a transaction into a transaction exception, create a more concrete **TransactionException** out of the throwable and pass the throwable as `$previous` to its constructor.

1. allows you to have unchecked exceptions, 2. allows you to have checked exceptions.

---

Usage Example:

Implement *2. Wrap and Bubble*:

```php
class TransactionFailedException extends RuntimeException
{}
```

```php
/**
 * @throws TransactionFailedException
 */
public static function transaction(callable $function): void
{
    try {
        $function();
    } catch (Throwable $failure) {
        throw new TransactionFailedException('Transaction failed', 0, $failure);
    }
}
```

Then add `TransactionFailedException` to the unchecked exceptions (if still necessary, RuntimeException could be already in).